# How to create different .cs files

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way in `WPF` for the events (such as Click) to have the method in a different `.cs` file rather than the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` (for instance)? In other words, when i go to select the mouse down event and double click on it to write the method - the method appears in MainWindow.xaml.cs .. is there a way to redirect this to another file? I would need access to all of the attributes/fields that i use (such as textboxes, buttons etc) that are on the MainWindow.....

In my `MainWindow.xaml`, I' have methods dealing with `gotFocus` and `lostFocus` etc. I don't want to be dealing with sockets and connection within the same file (as I feel that is bad design).  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to, you could create a [Partial Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
 to put your event handlers in. It will still be part of the MainWindow class, but it will be in a different file.

That said, a better design would be to move your code for dealing with sockets and connections out into its own class or classes, while leaving the event handling code in MainWindow.xaml.cs. Partial classes aren't really the right tool to use in this case, IMO.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want to do - but if i wanted to add an event ... say "somethingClick" when i select "MouseDown event" to write it's method, wouldn't it be directed to MainWindow.xaml.cs file? How would i re-direct this to go into my own class?

Comment: Yeah, by default the somethingClick method would be put in MainWindow.xaml.cs, but all you have to do is cut it from there and paste it into your partial class file. And to create the partial class file, just add a new class in a new file, and call it 'partial class MainWindow'

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like what you want to do is use a MVVM design pattern (WPF lends itself very nicely to this, BTW).

[here is a good article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx),[here is one by Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/), and a google will reveal much more

it sounds like you need to [look into commanding](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/11/11/wpf-commands/) as well

Answer (score 1):

If your notion is to remove the dependency between the UI and Codebehind then probably the best idea, since you are using WPF is MVVM pattern. So you that your view doesn't have to know about what is happening when you click on the button etc. Or else you can event think about ICommand  to separate the commanding from your code behind. exactly something like @Mead'Dib  has recommended.

The other area which you can explore is to think about something like Command Pattern where you can separate the Receiver and invoker. So that you are not tightly coupled with the code behind. So just think about using some kind of pattern that will make you safe when maintenance issues there.